# Why does var work inside a lambda in Kotlin?

Tags: lambda, kotlin, closures

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4732617/1065835) I read about how closures were managed in Java. As to Kotlin, I expected that a variable had to be effectively final as well (in other words `val`, not `var`) to be available in a lambda function.

But the following code snippet works.

```
var stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
stringBuilder.append("Old")
stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
stringBuilder.append("New")

sample_btn.setOnClickListener {
    Toast.makeText(this, stringBuilder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    // New is shown
}
```

So `stringBuilder` doesn't need to be final to be used in the lambda funcation. I wonder what's going on under the hood, and why my code works.

Comment: What's the scope of `stringBuilder` here?